# Revert merge commit resolved with 'ours' strategy

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

A colleague of mine merge our develop branch back into the feature branch with '--strategy=ours', or with a series of operation that effectively resulted in discarding develop changes.

I was trying to find a way to revert the merge commit to bring the changes back but I was not able to find a simple recipe for it:

- *git revert -m 1 merge-sha1* doesn't works since there is no change against the first parent
- *git revert -m 2 merge-sha1* does bring develop changes into our branch but it seems to also get rid of a lot of changes which were not in develop that we wanted to keep.

I searched online and found some articles about situation like these or similar but couldn't figure out the right way to cleanly resolve this mess. In the end we made a new branch from right before the faulty merge and started from scratch. How could this situation be resolved in a clean way?

EDIT:

To better explain:

```
--A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I
         \           \
          D'--E'--F'--M--G'
```

`M` is the faulty merge, that discarded all changes from `D` to `G`. 
With the first option (`-m 1`), nothing happens. With the second options (`-m 2`), the revert seems to remove changes happened in `D'`-`F'` together with adding the removed changes.

Sorry, forgot to add that `git reset` is not an option since the merge has already been pushed to the remote repo and `git push --force` is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... I searched online and found some articles about situation like these or similar but couldn't figure out the right way to cleanly resolve this mess. In the end we made a new branch from right before the faulty merge and started from scratch. How could this situation be resolved in a clean way?

That actually *is* the right / clean way—though you don't need a new *branch* per se, as branch names are not all that important to Git.

> [given this graph]
>
> ```
> --A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I   <-- br1
>          \           \
>           D'--E'--F'--M--G'   <-- br2
> ```
>
> [where] `M` is the faulty merge, that discarded all changes from D to G ...

All *revert* options work by comparing `M` to one of its two parents.  Since `M` was run with `--ours`, its tree matches either `F` or `F'` (whichever of these is the first parent):

I'm not quite sure why you labeled some commits with prime-marks (`D'-E'-F'` etc) but if `M` *should have* been a real merge, rather than `--ours`, you need to re-run the merge.  You can do this any way you like but the easiest is to check out either of its parents, here `G` and `F'` respectively, and then run `git merge` with the hash ID of its other parent.  In general I'd recommend keeping the first- and second-parent-ness properties of the two, so I would do:

```
git checkout <hash-of-G>
git merge <hash-of-F'>
```

Finish the merge as usual and, if Git itself doesn't commit it, commit it:

```
                      _________
                     /         \
--A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I     \   <-- br1
         \           \          M2   <-- HEAD
          D'--E'--F'--M--G'     /   <-- br2
                   \___________/
```

Then, depending on what you want to see, either cherry-pick `G'` and forcibly reset `br2` to point to the result:

```
                      _________
                     /         \
--A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I     \   <-- br1
         \           \          M2--G"   <-- br2
          D'--E'--F'--M--G'     /
                   \___________/
```

(but this is a non-fast-forward case that requires all other users of `br2` to adjust), or you can just drop a temporary name (tag or branch) here, `git checkout br2`, `git merge` the temporary name, and then delete the temporary name:

```
                      _________
                     /         \
--A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I     \   <-- br1
         \           \          M2--M3   <-- br2
          D'--E'--F'--M--G'-----/---/
                   \___________/
```

Note that the merge base when producing merge `M3` is both `F'` and `G` so `git merge` will, by default, do a recursive merge of those two to use as a merge base; it will then merge both `M2` and `G'` against that virtual merge base to produce `M3`.  You can use `git merge -s resolve` to pick one of `F'` or `G` at random as the merge base, which may be less messy if there are merge conflicts in making the virtual merge base.  If you made `M2` correctly —for some definition of "correctly" anyway—the result of `-s resolve` will be the same.

In the end, Git doesn't care *how* you get to your final commit graph and the snapshots that are in those commits.  All Git really cares about is preserving the commits (which preserves the graph).  Branch *names* just serve to find the tip commits: the entry points into the graph.  Various individual commands, such as `git diff` and `git cherry-pick`, compare specific commits, perhaps finding them *from* the graph, and will do interesting things from there, so you might want specific commits to have specific contents so make these as interesting as possible.

Meanwhile, `git merge` itself just looks at the graph to find the merge base, then does *two* diffs (from merge base to each tip commit) to find changes, then combine the changes.  There are some exceptions of course: `-s ours` makes the new mergecommit with the same graph links as a true merge, but completely ignores one of the two branch tips and therefore doesn't have to bother finding a merge base, it just re-uses the tree from the then-current commit.  And, as noted in passing above, `-s recursive` finds *all* the merge bases.  Usually there's only one, so there's nothing special about this, but there are ways to get more than one merge base, for which `-s recursive` just merges the merge bases to produce a new (temporary) commit to use as the merge base.  (After finishing the merge-as-a-verb process, it releases the temporary commit to be reclaimed by Git's usual garbage collection process.)

Comment: I marked the branch commit with prime because I was too lazy to use different letters and I thought it would better show the contemporaneity, no relation is intended between `E` and `E'`, even if it sounds confusing.

Comment: Anyway, I like your solution, I was hoping for something that would lead to a less intricate network but I guess the situation is quite difficult to handle per se, without adding more stuff. Just for completeness, first parent was `F'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to revert back to a particular commit, you simply need to run `git reset <sha1>`. This should work regardless of the type of commit that succeeds it. Run `git log` to find the most recent commit before the merge, then reset to it.

Comment: Thanks but as I added in the question `git reset` is not an option since commit has already been pushed.

Comment: @bracco23 Then you will need to force push. This is true regardless of the method you choose as you want to rewrite history.

Comment: Again, push force is not an option since remote refuse to accept it. I also personally think it is not a good thing to do it when working in a shared project, but that is just my opinion.